# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_list' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Update:
I put the image_list and file_list before and i didn't have a problem with it, but now it says AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'save', here's the new code:

```html
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os.path  
import PIL.ImageDraw 

def get_images(directory=None):
    image_list = [] 
    file_list = []
    if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd() 
    directory_list = os.listdir(directory) 
    for entry in directory_list:
        absolute_filename = os.path.join(directory, entry)
        try: 
            image = PIL.Image.open(absolute_filename)
            file_list+= [entry]
            image_list+=[image]
        except IOError:
            pass 
    return image_list, file_list

def alter_one_image(directory=None):
    directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  
    chungus = os.path.join(directory, 'big_chungus.jfif')
    chungus_img = PIL.Image.open(chungus)
    chungus_small = chungus_img.resize((89, 87))
    chungus_img.paste(chungus_small, (1162, 966), mask=chungus_small)
    new=PIL.Image.new
    return new
def alter_all_images(directory=None):
    if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd()
        new_directory = os.path.join(directory,'modified')
        try:
            os.mkdir(new_directory)
        except OSError:
            pass
            image_list, file_list = get_images(directory)
            for n in range (len(image_list)):
                print n
                filename,filetype = file_list[n].split('.')
                curr_image = image_list[n]
                new_image = alter_one_image(curr_image)
                new_image_filename = os.path.join(new_directory, filename+'.png')
                new_image.save(new_image_filename)
```

Here's the full traceback error:

```
alter_all_images()
```

0

AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 alter_all_images()

C:\Users\terrazg20\Documents\GabeTerrazas_1_4_5AlterAllImages.py in alter_all_images(directory)
     43                 new_image = alter_one_image(curr_image)
     44                 new_image_filename = os.path.join(new_directory, filename+'.png')
---> 45                 new_image.save(new_image_filename)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the error you are getting.

Comment: Please include the complete error traceback, we don't want to have to guess at what point the error occured.

Comment: Please post the error traceback

Comment: In `get_images()`, `image_list` doesn't get initialised to an empty list if `directory` is `None`.

Comment: In `get_images()`, `image_list` doesn't get initialised to an empty list if `directory` is *not* `None`.

Comment: Summary: a) full stacktrace, b) error in `get_images()` (it was the first time I see such coincidence in comments :)

Answer (score 1):

get_images() doesn't initialise empty lists for both 'file_list' and 'image_list' if directory is equal to None. Just Initialize them at the beginning of the function and it should fix the issue. Like this:

```
def get_images(directory=None):
    image_list = [] 
    file_list = []
    if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd()
```